# Mustache tags not working?

Tags: jquery, templates, mustache

Everytime i try to use the Mustache.js section tags for templating the content from json never gets passed or function breaks. I am not sure what i am doing wrong and tired of searching for a solution through forums and past questions. If anyone could help me i will be extremely grateful.

Here is my function:

```
$('body').on('click', '.logo', function(){
        alert('clicked');
        var request1 = $.ajax({
                url: "js/projects.js",
                dataType:'json',
            }).then(function(response){
                    var data = response.projects;
                    var template = $('#testing_tmp').html();
                    var project = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                    return project;
            });
            $.when(request1).then(function(t) {
                $('#header').html(t);

            });
        });
```

Here is my template-mustache:

```
<script id="testing_tmp" type="text/template">
    {{#projects}}
        <div class='testingMus'>
            <div class='project'><figure><img src='{{{largePic}}}' alt='' />
            <figcaption class='caption'><span>{{genre}}</span></figcaption class='caption'></figure></div>
           </div>
        </div>
    {{/projects}}
    </script>
```

Sample of my json:

```
{
    "projects":[
        {
            "id":"0",
            "title":"Heller Recipes", 
            "description":"This web applications was developed to keep track of my dads recipes and make them easily accesible.He is now able to check each user and make a dinner based on what everybody likes or in some cases dont like. ",
            "technologiesUsed":"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0",
            "projectLink":"http://www.google.com",
            "genre":"web-app",
            "largePic":"img/projects/heller-recipes/thumb.jpg", 
            "desktopImg":"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",
            "desktopMobile":"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"
        },  
        {
            "id":"1",
            "title":"3D Animation", 
            "description":"Created using 4D Cinema Max, a 3d anitmation program that allows you to create realistic renderings and animations.",
            "technologiesUsed":"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0",
            "projectLink":"http://www.google.com",
            "genre":"3d",
            "largePic":"img/projects/4dmax.jpg",
            "desktopImg":"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",
            "desktopMobile":"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `{{#projects}}{{/projects}}`  inside of your template but in your success-callback you pass the `response.projects` to the  template. As of that the root element is an array and not an object containing the property `projects`.

You would need to pass `response` to your template directly.